Estne in lingua Latina verbum pro die ante heri?
Estne in lingua Latina verbum pro die ante heri? Scitis, ut Croaticum verbum "prekjučer" (quod legitur "trans-heri").
SUMMARY: Did Latin have a word for the day before yesterday?

Precor deis quod sit.

Est quippe vocabulum Latinum designans hoc quod rogas, scilicet nudiustertius vel (si mavis separatim scribere) nudius tertius.
Ut planius explicem sensum huius vocabuli ad litteram, nudiustertius potest dividi (ut Gallia!) in partes tres: "num (i.e. nunc) dies tertius." Hodie enim est dies tertius post diem quem designare vis (ut numerantur dies a Romanis).
Ecce Palinurus (in principio Curculionis T. M. Plauti) deridens amicum suum:

Ostium occlusissimum, caruitne febris te herí vel nudiustertius et heri cenavistine?

...quod anglice sic reddi potest:

O most closed of doors, have you been free of a fever yesterday or the day before, and did you eat yesterday?

Advertendum autem est illud nudiustertius esse adverbium indeclinabile. Non ergo licet declinare ut nomen, nec dicendum est *nudiumtertium.
Licet etiam uti vocabulo nudius (scil. nunc dies) cum quantolibet numero ordinali. Exempli gratia nudius quartus sibi vult "tres dies abhinc."
